# Connecting to an Oracle database

Tags: c#, database-connection

I am using sqlplus to connect my database directly but now I try connect to host from c# but it does not work.

I tried the Oracle format with Msdaroa user id pass and host and still open not working it said cant find the host

Comment: you need to give an example of what you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i already fix that up i only needed to connection from Local disk and no  Lan disk

i tried that "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=serverName;User ID=MyUserID; Password=MyPassword;"
and it worked for me